# ActivityNotFoundException during feature activation

Tags: solution-package, visual-studio-2012, solution-deployment, workflow-variable, workflow-manager

I have a workflow 2013 included in Full trust solution (WSP). When I add a variable of type `DynamicValue` to the workflow and try to deploy the solution using VS 2012 I get the error during feature activation:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features':
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ActivityNotFoundException: The activity
>   named 'WorkflowXaml_ed00d3bd_4796_41ba_b288_35ce2226f89a' from scope
>   '/SharePoint/default/248fadea-e82b-4d15-bf03-d00b7947ca36/a6b8142a-8120-4823-a855-f400460ec143'
>   was not found. HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId:
>   1cc4b55f-876a-4ad4-bdee-7a897c1992cd. NodeId: ZG-SP2013-02. Scope:
>   /SharePoint/default/248fadea-e82b-4d15-bf03-d00b7947ca36/a6b8142a-8120-4823-a855-f400460ec143.
>   Client ActivityId : 2e0290fd-765b-435c-a

Markup generated in *Workflow.xaml* when the variable is added:

```
  <Variable x:TypeArguments="p:DynamicValue" Name="drStId" />
```

If I delete the variable, the workflow gets deployed successfully.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Other `ActivityNotFoundException` posts on SP SE aren't related to this issue.

**EDIT:**

If I remove some other variable and add aforementioned *drStId* variable then solution gets deployed successfully. Normally I counted number of variables in WF, and the limit appears to be 50. I wanted to confirmed that by creating a new blank workflow with exactly the same variables. Then I added 10 more variables in new workflow, but it deploys successfully. So limit of 50 variables isn't correct, but some kind of limit is definitely in place during deployment, I just need to figure out which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption about variable count limit was correct. You can have 50 variables per activity, in my case `Sequence`.

More on conducted analysis: http://slavensemper.blogspot.com/2014/12/maximum-number-of-variables-per-activity.html

Answer (score 0):

I was working with SharePoint workflow 2013 in Visual Studio 2013.  The workflow has been deployed many times.  All of a sudden the above troublesome has been occurred.  I did re-register workflowservice, but no use.  My workflow only have 15 variables declared.  So the above limitations are not applicable to me.

When I deleted an unused variable from workflow, the workflow has been deployed correctly.